# How to make custom properties in Properties Window to refresh upon change via code?

Tags: vb.net

Here is some code:

```
ReadOnly Property X() As Integer
    Get
        Return PointerX
    End Get
End Property

ReadOnly Property Y() As Integer
    Get
        Return PointerY
    End Get
End Property

Private Sub Proj_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseMove
    PointerX = e.X
    PointerY = e.Y
End Sub
```

I want to make the Properties Window to update the properties for X and Y at each MouseMove, so they become immediately visible for the user. I know it is stupid, but it is my assignment.

[image]

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Your code is confusing me.  Obviously this is runtime code because there is no MouseMove event at design time.  But you are showing two variables `PointerX` and `PointerY` that you are updating.  The `PropertyGrid` control uses an `Object`.  What object is it using?

Comment: I haven't used such control as PropertyGrid. I am lowly familiar with VB and am not sure what is confusing you.

Comment: I think I get it... I do not have and don't want to create a custom PropertyGrid control. I want to use the default one, which appears in runtime mode automatically.

Comment: I have no idea what you are seeing at runtime.  Try linking a picture of your screen shot.

Comment: http://img337.imageshack.us/img337/6468/captureurj.png

Comment: That's the `PropertyGrid` control.  What object are you passing to it on the `SelectedObject` property?

Comment: The point is that I haven't created this PropertyGrid control, and I don't know how to reach it via code. Obviously it is created automatically by the application. I want to reach it but I do not know how.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend pursuing this project in WPF using the OnPropertyChanged event to notify all listeners when a property is changed.  Then, make the PropertyGrid listen to all such events on the object which it represents, updating the appropriate property.  WPF is great for this stuff...

Comment: Sorry, I am not very familiar with VB and not exactly sure how this can be done. Could you please show me an example or something?

Comment: Can I do that for the default PropertyGrid, which is visible at runtime (without I create a new one in the control). How do I get its object?

Comment: For an intro to WPF, click [here](http://www.wpftutorial.net/WPFIntroduction.html).  For an example of using property notifications click [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx).

Comment: I have the OnPropertyChanged function now, but I do not have and don't want to create a custom PropertyGrid control. I want to use the default one, which appears in runtime mode automatically. You can see it here: http://img337.imageshack.us/img337/6468/captureurj.png
How do I make these values refresh when OnPropertyChanged is executed? How to bind it?

Answer (score 0):

That's not a Windows Form project.

You created a Windows Control Library which includes a default UserControl and when you "run", you are seeing your UserControl being hosted, which is why you are seeing a PropertyGrid control.

You need to create or add a new project to your solution that is a Windows Form Application, and set it as the "Starup Project" (right mouse click the Form project and select "Set as Startup Project").

After you rebuild your solution, your UserControl "Proj" will be available from the ToolBox, which you can place on your form.

Comment: Yes, I know that. Even if I place it on a form, I will need to use the form's default PropertyGrid to show and refresh the coordinates, so I believe the problem remains. How do I get the default PropertyGrid object (of form or control, it is the same)?

Comment: @ГеоргиГеоргиев I think you need to explain what your assignment is here.  What you keep describing about default PropertyGrids makes no sense.

Comment: My assignment is to create a control which has 2 custom properties X and Y, which are dynamically updated with the current mouse pointer position. Forget about the form. If put on a form, the properties will not be visible, I understand that.